# VNC over Raspberry Pi router using port forwarding

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc, port-forwarding

I have configured Raspberry Pi as a router and access point for client devices, and it works without problem.

It works with usage of hostapd and isc-dhcp-sever programs, but there is a challenge: enabling VNC connections through the Raspberry Pi router. Below you can find schematics of what has been done.

```
intranet <--> [x.x.x.x|eth0] Raspberry Pi 2 [192.168.1.1/24|wlan0] <--> clients
```

My idea was to enable for port forwarding in rc.local file, but it is not executing code for some unknown reason.

Below you can find content of the rc.local file:

```
# enable VCN port forwarding
vncport=5900
for (( counter=0; counter<91; counter++ ))
do
    port=$[10010+counter]
    address=$[10+counter]
    iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport "$port" -j DNAT --to 192.168.1."$address":"$vncport"
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1."$address" --dport "$port" -j ACCEPT
done

# access point code
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script works and creates this iptables entries:

```
# iptables -L FORWARD -nv
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         tcp dpt:10010
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.11         tcp dpt:10011
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.12         tcp dpt:10012
...
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.98         tcp dpt:10098
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.99         tcp dpt:10099
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.100        tcp dpt:10100

# iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -nv
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 1746 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10010 to:192.168.1.10:5900
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10011 to:192.168.1.11:5900
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10012 to:192.168.1.12:5900
...
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10098 to:192.168.1.98:5900
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10099 to:192.168.1.99:5900
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10100 to:192.168.1.100:5900
```

Put your script in a own file with `#!/bin/bash` as line 1, give it execute permission, test it and when ready, call it from `rc.local`
`

Comment: Thanks for the help... my question is, will this as it is work, I mean port forwarding over isc-dhcp-server

Comment: of course, the only way to know for sure is to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `/etc/rc.local` file is interpreted by `sh` (the first line of this file reads `#!/bin/sh -e`). You have used a C-style `for` loop, which only works in `bash`. I believe that's the root cause.

Either replace the first line of `/etc/rc.local` with `#!/bin/bash -e`, or rewrite your loop in sh-compatible manner:

```
counter=0
while [ "$counter" -lt 91 ]
do
    port=$((10010+counter))
    address=$((10+counter))
    iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport "$port" -j DNAT --to 192.168.1."$address":"$vncport"
    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1."$address" --dport "$port" -j ACCEPT
    counter=$((1+counter))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly linux uses same firewall, Thus configure firewall properly in any *Desktop Linux* and upon verification copy iptable rules to Raspberry Pi. I guess this may help out with configuration error. Although a cheap trick :)